# How to test an Angular Factory which uses Parse SDK

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, parse-platform, jasmine, karma-runner

*This is my first question here. I'll try to do my best. I searched a lot before posting*

I'm developing an angularJS application relying on the Javascript [ParseSDK](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide).
I have convinced myself to dive in testing recently, so I am a beginner.

I have this factory `UserFactory` that wraps around the SDK so everything is clean and modular the Angular way. ie: SDK is only used through factories (not controller nor directives).

It goes like this:

```
myModule.factory('UserFactory', ['$q', function($q){
    var User = Parse.User.extend({
      // Instance methods
    },{
      // static/class methods
      // Overrides Parse.User.current() to wrap current User in promise
      current: function(){
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
          if(currentUser)
              deferred.resolve(currentUser);
          else
              deferred.reject("No current user");
          return deferred.promise;
      }
    });

    return User;
}]);
```

My question: **How to test for `UserFactory.current()` knowing it uses an external service?**
I've looked into mocking the Parse SDK but don't know how to do it since it's not angular related (ie: can't use httpBackend).

My current test file:

```
describe("Unit: UserFactory", function(){
    var UserFactory;

    beforeEach(function(){
      module("myModule");
      inject(function(_UserFactory_){
          UserFactory = _UserFactory_;
      });
    });

    it("should return current User", function(){
      // What to expect ?
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What i usually do, in this case, is mocking the `Parse.User.current()`, making it return a value of my choice, and comparing this value after the call to make sure it has called this method (alongside with some spies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
describe("Unit: UserFactory", function(){
    var UserFactory;

    beforeEach(function(){
      module("myModule");
      inject(function(_UserFactory_){
          UserFactory = _UserFactory_;
          $rootScope  = _$rootScope_;
      });
    });

    describe('current()', function() {

      var successCallback, errorCallback;


      beforeEach(function() {
        successCallback = jasmine.createSpy('success');
        errorCallback   = jasmine.createSpy('error');
      });

      it("promise should resolve if Parse.User.current is truthy", function(){

        spyOn(Parse.User, 'current').and.returnValue(true);

        UserFactory.current().then(successCallback, errorCallback);

        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(successCallback.calls.count()).toBe(1);
        expect(errorCallback.calls.count()).toBe(0);

        expect(Parse.User.current).toHaveCalledOnce();

      });

      it("promise should reject if Parse.User.current is falsy", function(){

        spyOn(Parse.User, 'current').and.returnValue(false);

        UserFactory.current().then(successCallback, errorCallback);

        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(errorCallback.calls.count()).toBe(1);
        expect(successCallback.calls.count()).toBe(0);

        expect(Parse.User.current).toHaveCalledOnce();

      });


    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks that puts me in the right track. I still have a problem.
the `spyOn(Parse.User,"current")` throws **Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined**

Comment: OK I had the wrong jasmine/karma-jasmine version. It works on the 2_0 branche